# Import passwords from LastPass to Firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords, import, lastpass

I have Firefox 48 and Ubuntu 16.04.
I'm migrating from **LastPass** to default **Firefox Password Manager**.

I have exported my passwords with LastPass and it created a file (no extension, but I think it's CSV).
I have installed the **Password Exporter** extension (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/) and I tried to import that file, but it say that it can't import that file.
So I tried to convert it to XML using [this](https://github.com/anirudhjoshi/lastpass2keepass) python script, also I imported that file to **KeePass v2** and exported to both XML and CSV. 
Again I tried to import those files and the CSV file can't be imported, instead, with the XML files the extension does not throw any error, still it does nothing because no passwords are actually imported.

Is there a working way to import those passwords to my Firefox Password Manager?

Thanks

Comment: 1) why are you doing this? You area replacing a tool with a worse one that can only be used on the browser... Anyway 2) csv or xml don't mean anything. Because they can be formatted in many different ways on contain different fields. You have to produce files in the exact format Firefox expects.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend the FF add-on called KeeFox. It allows you to use a KeePass database for your FF passwords (which can then be synced with e.g. Dropbox).

Comment: @Bakuriu Worse in what ways?

Comment: @Bakuriu LastPass is a horrible tool riddled with self-promoting ads, an unusable user interface, a myriad of long-standing bugs, and is closed source software whose security cannot be independently verified. I would be cautious about calling the Firefox password manager "worse".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LastPass add-on for Firefox has an option to do this. Choose `Tools` → `Advanced Tools` → `Export To` → `Firefox`

[image]

Comment: This option seems to be not available in Firefox anymore. It is now only possible to export to CSV. But the CSV cannot be imported in FF, so far as I know. Also not with [Passwort Exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/), that does not work with FF Quantum.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an up-to-date method answer:

Export from Lastpass:

1. Open your Vault
2. Click on the three dots (More Options) in the bottom left corner and then: Advanced > Export
3. Save the .csv file

Import into Firefox Lockwise (source: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/wiki/switching-to-firefox#wiki_importing_passwords)

1. Navigate to about:config in the Firefox URL bar
2. Search for signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled and ensure it is true
3. Navigate to about:logins
4. Click on the three dots on the top right corner of the page and then Import from a File...
5. Select your file and follow the instructions
   and voilà!

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It worked for me

Comment: Needs an update for new lasspass, but does work.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple python script to transform the export into import.csv

`file="Export.csv"
print("""
"hostname","username","password","formSubmitURL","httpRealm","usernameField","passwordField" """ )
for line in open(file):
    l=line.split(',')
    first, rest = l[:1], l[1:] 
    url=l[0]
    if url=="http://" : url = url + l[4]
    print('"'+url+'",'+'"'+l[1]+'",'+'"'+l[2]+'",'+ '"'+url+'",'+'"","",""')`

(as the method Tools → Advanced Tools → Export To → Firefox seems to be gone.)